# JS if inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to rewrite this as a for loop; my attempt below failed. Any ideas?

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);
function resizeFrame()
    if ($(window).width() < 232){
        $("#grid-content").css( 'width', '232px' );
    }else if ($(window).width() < 458){
        $("#grid-content").css( 'width', '232px' );
    }else if ($(window).width() < 684){
        $("#grid-content").css( 'width', '458px' );
    }else if ($(window).width() < 910){
        $("#grid-content").css( 'width', '684px' );
    }else if ($(window).width() < 1136){
        $("#grid-content").css( 'width', '910px' );
    };
};
```

The result is the div (#grid-content) is really wide around 3000px, regardless of window size.

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);
function resizeFrame()
    for (var x=232;x<=3000;x=x+226){
        if ($(window).width() < x ){
            $("#grid-content").css( 'width', x +'px' );
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Is the missing `{` from `function resizeFrame()` a typo in your question?

Comment: use `var` for declaring `x` inside your for loop or it will become a global variable otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a loop to round-down-to-discrete-steps, it's simple arithmetic.

```
function resizeFrame() {
    var w= $(window).width();
    w-= (w-6) % 226;
    if (w<232) w= 232;
    $('#grid-content').width(w);
}
```

Comment: Is it me, or does the expected result from OP's `if()` statement(s) seem out of sync with the expected result from the `for()` loop?

Comment: @patrick: oh, good point, I hadn't spotted that! The round-down behaviour in the `if` does seem much more likely to be useful than rounding up. Changed answer to round down instead of up. (Also discarded the `3000` check since my guess is this and the 1136 limit in the `if` case are merely arbitrary upper bounds.)

Comment: thanks. if you have the time could you explain this a little?

Comment: `n-= n%chunk` is an idiom to round down to the nearest multiple of `chunk`. It uses the `%` operator to divide by `chunk` and take the remainder; subtracting the remainder from the original value leaves the rounded-down multiple. (The `-6` is needed to align the chunks so that they're at `6, 232, ...` instead of `0, 226, ...`.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to exit the loop on the first match so it doesn't continue until the end, like this:

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);
function resizeFrame() {
    for (x=232;x<=3000;x=x+226){
        if ($(window).width() < x ){
            $("#grid-content").css( 'width', x +'px' );
            break; //add this
        }
    }
}
```

You can optimize a bit though, like this:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load resize", function () {
    var w = $(window).width();
    for (var x=232;x<=3000;x+=226) {
        if (w < x ) {
            $("#grid-content").width(x);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 while @bobince showed a simpler solution, you correctly pointed out why his for loop fails.